# Django ORM pass model method value in aggregate

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

This is my models:

```
class Bill(models.Model):
    user =  models.OneToOneField(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='user_bill'
    )
    flat_rent = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=6,
        decimal_places=2,
        default=0.00
    )
    gas_bill = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=6,
        decimal_places=2,
        default=0.00
    )

    # Also i have many such decimalField here that calculated in get_total
    ===========================================


    def get_total(self):
        total = self.flat_rent + self.gas_bill
        return total
```

I am trying to pass this `get_total` mehtod value here:

```
user_wise = User.objects.filter(
            id=request.user.id
        ).aggregate(
            get_total=Sum('user_bill__get_total')
        )
```

in my case, i have to query everything from `user` with `related_name`, that is why i am aggregate the model method here.

Can anyone help how can i pass this `get_total` method in aggrigate?

I dont want to pass like this. `Bill.objects.get(user__id=request.user.id).get_total`

Can anyone help to achieve this?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do like this:

```
from django.db.models import F, Sum

user_wise = Bill.objects.filter(
        user=request.user
    ).annotate(
        get_total=F('flat_rent') + F('gas_bill')
    ).aggregate(
        total=Sum('get_total')
    )
```

Also, as it is a [OneToOne](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/) relation between `User` and `Bill`, you do not need a complicated solution like this. You can simply use:

```
user_wise = request.user.user_bill.get_total()
```